# Add a Start/Title Screen to Pygame Code

Tags: python, pygame

I am wondering how to add a start screen or title screen to this game. I would have a .png as the background and then add the controls in later. Could someone explain how one must do this. All I need is that when I press a button, the game will start, and the game will open with an .png.

This code already works:

```
from sys import argv
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from maze import Maze
class Game:

  def __init__(self, diff, dim, path):
    self.size = (800,600)
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Rhino Rampage')
    self.titleScreen = pygame.image.load("TitleScreen.png")
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 55)
    text = font.render("Loading...", 1, (255,255,255))
    rect = text.get_rect()
    rect.center = self.size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2
    self.screen.blit(text, rect)

    pygame.display.update(rect)
    self.diff = diff
    self.dim = map(int, dim.split('x'))
    self.path = path

  def start(self):
    self.maze_obj = Maze(*self.dim)# pass args to change maze size: Maze(10, 10)
    if self.diff == 0:
      self.maze_obj.generate(self.maze_obj.maze[(0,0)])
    else:
      self.maze_obj.generate()
    self.draw_maze()
    self.reset_player()
    self.loop()

  def reset_player(self):
    # Make the sprites for the player.
    w, h = self.cell_width - 3, self.cell_height - 3
    rect = 0, 0, w, h
    rhino = 0, 0, w, h
    base = pygame.Surface((w,h))
    base.fill( (255,255,255) )
    self.red_p = base.copy()
    self.green_p = base.copy()
    self.blue_p = base.copy()
    self.rhino_p = base.copy()
    player = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
    self.goldy = base.copy()
    if self.path == 1:
      r = (255,0,0)
      g = (0,255,0)
    else:
      r = g = (255,255,255)
    b = (0,0,255)
    gold = (0xc5,0x93,0x48)
    #pygame.draw.ellipse(self.red_p, r, rect)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.green_p, g, rect)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.rhino_p,(5,5,5),rhino)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.goldy, gold, rect)
    self.blue_p.blit(player,(0,0))

    # Make a same-size matrix for the player.
    self.player_maze = {}
    for y in xrange(self.maze_obj.rows):
      for x in xrange(self.maze_obj.cols):
        cell = {'visited' : 0} # if 1, draws green. if >= 2, draws red.
        self.player_maze[(x,y)] = cell
        self.screen.blit(base, (x*self.cell_width+2, y*self.cell_height+2))

    self.screen.blit(self.goldy, (x*self.cell_width+2, y*self.cell_height+2))
    self.cx = self.cy = 0
    self.curr_cell = self.player_maze[(self.cx, self.cy)] # starts at origin

    self.last_move = None # For last move fun

  def draw_maze(self):
    self.screen.fill( (255,255,255) )
    self.cell_width = self.size[0]/self.maze_obj.cols
    self.cell_height = self.size[1]/self.maze_obj.rows

    for y in xrange(self.maze_obj.rows):
      for x in xrange(self.maze_obj.cols):
        if self.maze_obj.maze[(x, y)]['south']: # draw south wall
          pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (0,0,0), \
            (x*self.cell_width, y*self.cell_height + self.cell_height), \
            (x*self.cell_width + self.cell_width, \
            y*self.cell_height + self.cell_height) )
        if self.maze_obj.maze[(x, y)]['east']: # draw east wall
          pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (0,0,0), \
            (x*self.cell_width + self.cell_width, y*self.cell_height), \
            (x*self.cell_width + self.cell_width, y*self.cell_height + \
            self.cell_height) )
    # Screen border
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), (0,0, self.size[0], self.size[1]), 1)
    pygame.display.update()

  def loop(self):
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.keep_going = 1

    while self.keep_going:
      moved = 0
      self.clock.tick(10)
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
          self.keep_going = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            self.keep_going = 0
          if event.key == K_r:
            self.reset_player()
          if event.key == K_DOWN:
            self.move_player('d')
            moved = 1
          if event.key == K_UP:
            self.move_player('u')
            moved = 1
          if event.key == K_LEFT:
            self.move_player('l')
            moved = 1
          if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            self.move_player('r')
            moved = 1
      keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
      if not moved:
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
          self.move_player('d')
        if keys[K_UP]:
          self.move_player('u')
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
          self.move_player('l')
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
          self.move_player('r')

      self.draw_player()
      pygame.display.update()

  def move_player(self, dir):
    no_move = 0
    try:
      if dir == 'u':
        if not self.maze_obj.maze[(self.cx, self.cy-1)]['south']:
          self.cy -= 1
          self.curr_cell['visited'] += 1
        else: no_move = 1
      elif dir == 'd':
        if not self.maze_obj.maze[(self.cx, self.cy)]['south']:
          self.cy += 1
          self.curr_cell['visited'] += 1
        else: no_move = 1
      elif dir == 'l':
        if not self.maze_obj.maze[(self.cx-1, self.cy)]['east']:
          self.cx -= 1
          self.curr_cell['visited'] += 1
        else: no_move = 1
      elif dir == 'r':
        if not self.maze_obj.maze[(self.cx, self.cy)]['east']:
          self.cx += 1
          self.curr_cell['visited'] += 1
        else: no_move = 1
      else:
        no_move = 1
    except KeyError: # Tried to move outside screen
      no_move = 1


    # Handle last move...
    if ((dir == 'u' and self.last_move == 'd') or \
        (dir == 'd' and self.last_move == 'u') or \
        (dir == 'l' and self.last_move == 'r') or \
        (dir == 'r' and self.last_move == 'l')) and \
        not no_move:
      self.curr_cell['visited'] += 1

    if not no_move:
      self.last_move = dir
      self.curr_cell = self.player_maze[(self.cx, self.cy)]

    # Check for victory.
    if self.cx + 1 == self.maze_obj.cols and self.cy + 1 == self.maze_obj.rows:
      print 'Congratumalations, you beat this maze.'
      self.keep_going = 0

  def draw_player(self):
    for y in xrange(self.maze_obj.rows):
      for x in xrange(self.maze_obj.cols):
        if self.player_maze[(x,y)]['visited'] > 0:
          if self.player_maze[(x,y)]['visited'] == 1:
            circ = self.green_p
          else:
            circ = self.red_p
          # draw green circles
          self.screen.blit(circ, (x*self.cell_width+2, y*self.cell_height+2))
    self.screen.blit(self.blue_p, (self.cx*self.cell_width+2, \
        self.cy*self.cell_height+2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pygame.init()
  args = argv[1:]
  diff = 0
  dim = '30x40'
  path = 1
  for arg in args:
    if '--diff' in arg:
      diff = int(arg.split('=')[-1])
    elif '--dim' in arg:
      dim = arg.split('=')[-1]
    elif '--path' in arg:
      path = int(arg.split('=')[-1])

  g = Game(diff, dim, path)
  g.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a state system, this being a way to detect what menu/part of the game is currently being shown.

For example, in your draw function, you can test if the state of the game is `"Main Menu"`, if so, you can draw what is only supposed to appear on the main menu. If the state of the game is `"Playing"`, then you could only draw what should be drawn when playing.

Example for your code:

```
state = "main menu"

#Screen is the surface that you would like to draw on.
#Current_state would be the state variable of the game, in our case, state.

def draw(screen,current_state):
    if current_state == "main menu":
        #draw what would appear on the main menu
    elif current_state == "playing":
        #draw what would appear while playing the game

    screen.flip()
```